# Clicking links quickly causes logout (session locking?)

Tags: php, session, cakephp, locking, cakephp-3.x

**The problem:**

When logged in, I click quickly to open multiple links in new tabs, the first one works fine, but the ones after aren't able to read the `user` from session, and cause the app to think "no user data = no access, redirect to login".

I was told this could be due to PHP's session locking. The idea being that the first page is loading, and by doing so, is reading the session. Before it's done, the next are trying to read the session, but it's still locked by the first.

It also happens if you simply click one link, then click a different link. Because the first link still hit the server causing it to lock the Session, so when the browser tries to take you to the 2nd instead, it can't read `user` and thinks you're not logged in.

This seems to be a very strange default behavior and I have to imagine someone has come up with a decent solution other than "just don't open multiple tabs" and "don't change your mind when clicking links".

This does not happen on my CakePHP 2.x PHP 5.x application, but IS happening on my CakePHP 3.x PHP 7.x application.

**One Suggested Solution:**

I was told to try Redis. While this sounds like a decent solution (Redis doesn't lock the session), it removes the [beneficial aspect of session locking](https://ma.ttias.be/php-session-locking-prevent-sessions-blocking-in-requests/) and also doesn't appear to work. Even after setting the CakePHP 3 app to use redis for sessions, and verifying it was writing the session data to redis, the problem still occurred.

**Questions:**

What is the standard method to deal with this problem? Does every CakePHP 3.x application actually have this bug by default?

**Note / Additional minor question:**

I noticed that the cookie value that Cake stores under "CAKE" changes on most page loads. The value is the session key (minus prefix). Does that mean it's setting a new session on every page load? If so, is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how session locking in PHP works, a locked session would *block* script execution until the session is being unlocked, it would *not* continue and leave you with no session access or an empty session.

If you are seeing a new session ID on every request, then that *might* be the problem (or a symptom of it), ie subsequent requests using already invalidated session IDs, that surely would leave you with an empty session, ie you'd be logged out.

Sessions are usually regenerated rather rarely, for example when logging in/out (to avoid replay attacks), or when the session times out. As a starting point, check your session timeout/lifetime configuration (`\Cake\Network\Session::$_lifetime`), also try a breakpoint in `\Cake\Network\Session::renew()` to check if it's being invoked unexpectedly and from where.

Comment: You seem to be on to something. It appears that the Session is being renewed EVERY time a link is clicked.  Still digging into why.

Comment: Turns out I was doing a `$this->Auth->setUser($user);` in the AppController which was renewing the session. Thanks for pointing me in that direction!